# javascript - calculate padding between elements programmatically

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is position 3 elements (could be 4/5/6, needs to be dynamic) vertically with position:absolute inside a container. I know this can be achieved with some CSS, but unfortunatley I have to do this in JavaScript so I need a function / algorithm that can calculate the container+children heights, then position them evenly.

So here's a test case:

```
<div id="element_1" style="position:relative;display:block;width:400px;height:768px">
    <div id="child_1" style="position:absolute;display:block;width:400px;height:105px"></div>
    <div id="child_2" style="position:absolute;display:block;width:400px;height:105px"></div>
    <div id="child_3" style="position:absolute;display:block;width:400px;height:105px"></div>
</div>
```

There are 3 children with a height of 105px each (children heights are always the same as each other, so the JavaScript I'm stuck on needs to position those 3 elements evenly with equal padding vertically.

I've tried something like:

```
var container; // dom instance of element_1
var children = []; // contains dom instances of each of the children (child_1, child_2, etc)

var container_height = container.getBoundingClientRect().height; // container is css3 scalable, hence the rect
var children_height = children[0].getBoundingClientRect().height; // for example
var padding = (container_height - (children_height*layers.length)) / layers.length;

for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    children[i].style.top = (padding*(i+1) + (i*children_height)) + 'px';
}
```

And it works somewhat, but there is a lot of extra space at bottom of the container, so it's not spacing evening.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: should there be padding before the first and after the third? why are you setting them absolute?

Comment: yes, all elements should be evenly spaced inside the container, so padding before the first element and after the last.

Comment: So total height minus height of divs and than divide by 4.

Comment: that did the trick, I was over thinking it plus repositioning those elements without multiplying the scale to the new positions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're just missing a `layer` in your code. Although I'm just guessing since `layer` isn't defined but that's `spaces` in my code, right?

`spaces` in my code refers to the, well, spaces between container and the children. Since you said there has to be "padding" between the container and the first and last divs, the count would always be the number of children + 1.

```js
function distribute() {
  const container = document.getElementById('element_1');
  const containerHeight = container.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const children = container.querySelectorAll('div');
  const childHeight = children[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const spaces = children.length + 1;
  const spaceInPx = (containerHeight - (childHeight * children.length)) / spaces;
  
  children.forEach((child, i) => {
    const position = spaceInPx * (i + 1) + (childHeight * i);
    
    child.style.top = `${position}px`;
  });
}

distribute();
```

```css
#element_1 {
  background: #000;
}

#element_1 div {
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="element_1" style="position:relative;display:block;width:400px;height:768px">
  <div id="child_1" style="position:absolute;display:block;width:400px;height:105px"></div>
  <div id="child_2" style="position:absolute;display:block;width:400px;height:105px"></div>
  <div id="child_3" style="position:absolute;display:block;width:400px;height:105px"></div>
</div>
```